# Unable to simplify exponential expression to its simplest form of trigonometric expression by Euler's formula

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex, trigonometry

Applying "FullSimplify" fails to simplify the following expressions:

Input:

`FullSimplify[(-0.0001+0.01*I)*E^((-1.6*10^7-2.1*10^8*I)*t)-(0.0001+0.01*I)*E^((-1.6*10^7+2.1*10^8*I)*t)]`

Output:

`(-0.0001 + 0.01 I) E^((-1.6*10^7 - 2.1*10^8 I) t) - (0.0001 +  0.01 I) E^((-1.6*10^7 + 2.1*10^8 I) t)`

However, in fact, by applying Euler's formula, the above expression can be manually simplified to:

`-2*(0.0001*Cos[-2.1*10^8*t] + 0.01*Sin[-2.1*10^8*t])*E^(-1.6*10^7*t)`

How can I do to simplify to this form in Mathematica？

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you already seen `ExpToTrig[]`?

Comment: `ExpToTrig[]` makes the expression more complex. The output is: `(-0.0001 - 0.01 I) Cos[(2.1*10^8 + 1.6*10^7 I) t] - (0.0001 - 0.01 I) Cosh[(1.6*10^7 + 2.1*10^8 I) t] + (0.01 - 0.0001 I) Sin[(2.1*10^8 + 1.6*10^7 I) t] + (0.0001 - 0.01 I) Sinh[(1.6*10^7 + 2.1*10^8 I) t]`. Moreover, the terms of Sinh[] and Cosh[] cannot be cancelled out with `TrigExpand[]` or `TrigReduce[]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = (-0.0001 + 0.01*I)*
   E^((-1.6*10^7 - 2.1*10^8*I)*t) - (0.0001 + 0.01*I)*
   E^((-1.6*10^7 + 2.1*10^8*I)*t)

ComplexExpand[expr, TargetFunctions -> {Abs, Arg}] // 
  TrigReduce // Chop
```

$$-0.0002 e^{-1.6\times 10^7 t} (1. \cos (2.1\times 10^8 t)-100. \sin (2.1\times 10^8 t))$$

Comment: Thanks, your method solved my problem!